# Temporary importhtml function

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

This is hard to explain so I will try my best. I know how to use import html. I have been using it for NFL research for a while now. But I don't like how many times i need to repeat it for every single player. I'm hoping there is a way to create a code or function that does the import html, and then outputs whatever would be in cell A2. For example, let's take this website: https://www.playerprofiler.com/nfl/andy-isabella/

Using `importhtml("https://www.playerprofiler.com/nfl/andy-isabella/", "Table", 2)` I want to only output the 5.3% target rate in that second table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is the solution you would like:

```
=query(importhtml("https://www.playerprofiler.com/nfl/andy-isabella/", "Table", 2),"select Col3 limit 1 label Col3 ''")
```

the query selects the third column, deletes the header and restricts the result to the next row.